# Latest Blog Post: Jack’s Bad Movies: Alien (1979)

Tags: discussion, featured, blog

<sup>NB - Newcomers, the contents of this question are completely replaced with each blog post. Don't get confused if you see you've already voted but don't recognize the post!</sup>

Latest Blog Post:

### [Jack’s Bad Movies: Alien (1979)](https://thesffblog.com/2024/04/jacks-bad-movies-alien-1979/)

> For Ripley there is no room in her cold heart for others.

---

### Science Fiction & Fantasy Community Blog

> This blog was originally part of the Stack Exchange network, but in fall 2016, support for Stack blogs was discontinued. Members of the community worked together to continue the blog privately, but still with strong ties to the network that brought us together.

### Interested in [contributing](https://thesffblog.com/contribute/)?

Contact me ([Jack B Nimble](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1148/jack-b-nimble)), or CreationEdge (if you can find him) about getting setup. Some ideas for the blog might be:

- Movie, book, or series reviews
- Coverage and experiences at Conventions
- Explanations and research about various fandoms (like the complete history of the [Marvel Cinematic Multiverse](https://thesffblog.com/2016/05/a-guide-to-the-marvel-cinematic-multiverse/))
- Or whatever else you might want to write about

And we don't buck the controversial issues like ['Is Starship Troopers pro-facist?'](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/07/starship-troopers-the-mobile-infantry-definitely-does-not-accept-hippies/) or is the ['Star Wars Canon Guide'](https://thesffblog.com/2015/01/the-new-star-wars-canon-guide/) the only post anyone ever reads?

**Answers to this post will be a backlog of previous posts.**

Comment: Needs more bad movie reviews

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd May your wish be granted.

Comment: And Jack said, "Let there be light", and it was good [Tim 7:27]

Comment: As an occasional contributor to SciFi SE, I'm confused what exactly this post is for. Is this a community run review blog?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro It is the community run blog, not necessarily for reviews (although that is common). Originally it was a part of StackExchange, but they abandoned their community blog support.

Comment: @JackBNimble You may want to add some of that information to the post for new users coming here from the main site.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd "Needs more bad movie reviews" [Here you go.](https://www.deviantart.com/meattrademark/art/SINEMA-281860270)

Comment: “They say you can’t please all people all at the same time, and last night all of those people were at my show” - Mitch Hedberg

Comment: Consider yourself funded

Answer (score 23):

### 2018

**December**

[What We Can Expect From 2019](https://thesffblog.com/2018/12/what-we-can-expect-from-2019/)

[Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse in 100 words or less – Spoiler Free](https://thesffblog.com/2018/12/spider-man-into-the-spider-verse-in-100-words-or-less-spoiler-free/)

**November**

[Ralph Breaks the Internet Review in 100 Words or Less – Spoiler-Free](https://thesffblog.com/2018/11/ralph-breaks-the-internet-review-in-100-words-or-less-spoiler-free/)

[Highlights from 2018 – 3rd Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2018/11/highlights-from-2018-3rd-quarter/)

**September**

[Jack’s Bad Movies: The Punisher (1989)](https://thesffblog.com/2018/09/jacks-bad-movies-the-punisher-1989/)

[Jack’s Bad Movies: Nick Fury: Agent of SHIELD (1998)](https://thesffblog.com/2018/09/jacks-bad-movies-nick-fury-agent-of-shield-1998/)

[Jack’s Bad Movies: Generation X (1996)](https://thesffblog.com/2018/09/jacks-bad-movies-generation-x-1996/)

[Jack’s Bad Movies: The Amazing Spider-Man (1977)](https://thesffblog.com/2018/09/jacks-bad-movies-the-amazing-spider-man-1977/)

**August**

[September: A Month of Bad Movies](https://thesffblog.com/2018/08/september-a-month-of-bad-movies/)

[Jack's Bad Movies: 5 Headed Shark Attack](https://thesffblog.com/2018/08/jacks-bad-movies-5-headed-shark-attack/)

[Orchid Dragonmaster](https://thesffblog.com/2018/08/orchid-dragonmaster/)

**July**

[Mike Needs a New Set of Lungs](https://thesffblog.com/2018/07/mike-needs-a-new-set-of-lungs/)

[Highlights from 2018 – 2nd Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2018/07/highlights-from-2018-2nd-quarter/)

**June**

[The Incredibles 2 Review in 100 Words or Less – Spoiler-Free](https://thesffblog.com/2018/06/the-incredibles-2-review-in-100-words-or-less-spoiler-free/)

**May**

[Netflix’s Cargo in 100 Words or Less – Spoiler-Free](https://thesffblog.com/2018/05/netflixs-cargo-in-100-words-or-less-spoiler-free/)

[Jack’s Bad Movies: Spectral (2016)](https://thesffblog.com/2018/05/jacks-bad-movies-spectral-2016/)

**April**

[Netflix’s “The Titan” in 100 Words (or Less)](https://thesffblog.com/2018/04/netflixs-the-titan-in-100-words-or-less/)

[Lost in Space in 100 words (or less)](https://thesffblog.com/2018/04/lost-in-space-in-100-words-or-less/)

[Highlights from 2018 – 1st Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2018/04/highlights-from-2018-1st-quarter/)

**March**

[Jack's Bad Movies: Captain America (1990)](https://thesffblog.com/2018/03/jacks-bad-movies-captain-america-1990/)

**February**

[The Orville - Season 1](https://thesffblog.com/2018/02/the-orville-season-1/)

**January**

[The Autobiography of James T. Kirk](https://thesffblog.com/2018/01/the-autobiography-of-james-t-kirk/)

[Highlights from 2017 – 4th Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2018/01/highlights-from-2017-4th-quarter/)

Comment: *"A couple of times I had to leave the room and come back, and I didn’t bother to pause."* Don't you care about journalistic integrity?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd The answer to your yes/no question is. No.

Answer (score 13):

### 2017

**December**

[The Autobiography of Jean-Luc Picard](https://thesffblog.com/2017/12/the-autobiography-of-jean-luc-picard/)

[Recent Star Wars Novels, Reviewed](https://thesffblog.com/2017/12/recent-star-wars-novels-reviewed/)

**November**

[Andy Weir's Artemis: A Novel](https://thesffblog.com/2017/11/andy-weirs-artemis-a-novel/)

[Justice League Does Fans, and DC, Justice](https://thesffblog.com/2017/11/justice-league-does-fans-and-dc-justice/)

[Live Chat: Star Wars Holiday Special](https://thesffblog.com/2017/11/live-chat-star-wars-holiday-special/)

**October**

[Highlights from 2017 – 3rd Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2017/10/highlights-from-2017-3rd-quarter/)

[Marvel’s Inhumans: Way better than you think.](https://thesffblog.com/2017/10/marvels-inhumans-way-better-than-you-think/)

**September**

[Jack's Bad Movies: Colossal (2016)](https://thesffblog.com/2017/09/jacks-bad-movies-colossal-2016/)

**August**

[Jack's Bad Movies: Knowing (2009)](https://thesffblog.com/2017/08/jacks-bad-movies-knowing-2009/)

**July**

[Jack’s Bad Movies: Spawn (1997)](https://thesffblog.com/2017/07/jacks-bad-movies-spawn-1997/)

[War For the Planet of the Apes is Strong](https://thesffblog.com/2017/07/war-for-the-planet-of-the-apes-is-strong/)

[Highlights from 2017 – 2nd Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2017/07/highlights-from-2017-2nd-quarter/)

[Spider-Man: Homecoming – A (almost entirely) spoiler-free review.](https://thesffblog.com/2017/07/spider-man-homecoming-a-almost-entirely-spoiler-free-review/)

**June**

[Jack’s Bad Movies: The Craft (1996)](https://thesffblog.com/2017/06/jacks-bad-movies-the-craft-1996/)

[Wonder Woman – A (mostly) spoiler-free review](https://thesffblog.com/2017/06/wonder-woman-a-mostly-spoiler-free-review/)

**May**

[Jack’s Bad Movies – Judge Dredd (1995)](https://thesffblog.com/2017/05/jacks-bad-movies-judge-dredd-1995/)

[Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2 review](https://thesffblog.com/2017/05/guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2-review/)

**April**

[Highlights from 2017 – 1st Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2017/04/highlights-from-2017-1st-quarter/)

[Jack’s Bad Movies – Circle of Iron (1978)](https://thesffblog.com/2017/04/jacks-bad-movies-circle-of-iron/)

[Ghost in the Shell – A (mostly) Spoiler-Free Review](https://thesffblog.com/2017/04/ghost-in-the-shell-a-mostly-spoiler-free-review/)

[Jack’s Bad Movies: Worst Movies of the Author’s Lifetime](https://thesffblog.com/2017/04/jacks-bad-movies-worst-movies-of-the-authors-lifetime/)

**March**

[Power Rangers’ Mighty Morph to the Big Screen](https://thesffblog.com/2017/03/power-rangers-mighty-morph-to-the-big-screen/)

[Jack’s Bad Movies – Robinson Crusoe on Mars (1964)](https://thesffblog.com/2017/03/jacks-bad-movies-robinson-crusoe-on-mars/)

[Interview With the Vampire by Anne Rice : Exploring the Questions of Good vs. Evil](https://thesffblog.com/2017/03/interview-with-the-vampire-by-anne-rice-exploring-the-questions-of-good-vs-evil/)

[Logan – A (mostly) Spoiler-Free Review](https://thesffblog.com/2017/03/logan-a-mostly-spoiler-free-review/)

[Gargoyles – A review](https://thesffblog.com/2017/03/gargoyles-a-review/)

**February**

[Legion Pilot – A (Mostly) Spoiler-Free Review](https://thesffblog.com/2017/02/legion-pilot-a-mostly-spoiler-free-review/)

[Jack’s Bad Movies – The Wraith (1986)](https://thesffblog.com/2017/02/jacks-bad-movies-the-wraith/)

[Powerless – Pilot](https://thesffblog.com/2017/02/powerless-pilot/)

**January**

[Highlights from 2016 – 4th Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2017/01/highlights-from-2016-4th-quarter/)

[Jack’s Bad Movies: Flight World War 2 (2015)](https://thesffblog.com/2017/01/jacks-bad-movies-flight-world-war-2/)
)

Answer (score 11):

### 2019

**December**

[Help Keep The SFF Blog Running](https://thesffblog.com/2019/12/help-keep-the-sff-blog-running/)

[Star Wars: Episode I – The Phantom Menace (1999) – Re-watch](https://thesffblog.com/2019/12/star-wars-episode-i-the-phantom-menace-1999-re-watch/)

**November**

[The Mandalorian (Pilot)](https://thesffblog.com/2019/11/the-mandalorian-pilot/)

**October**

[Yesterday (2019) – A Review](https://thesffblog.com/2019/10/yesterday-2019-a-review/)

[Highlights from 2019 – 3rd Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2019/10/highlights-from-2019-3rd-quarter/?preview=true)

**September**

[FanX Salt Lake Comic Convention (Fall 2019)](https://thesffblog.com/2019/09/fanx-salt-lake-comic-convention-fall-2019/)

**July**

[Highlights from 2019 – 2nd Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2019/07/highlights-from-2019-2nd-quarter/?preview=true)

**June**

[Men in Black: International a Spoiler Free Review](https://thesffblog.com/2019/06/men-in-black-international-a-spoiler-free-review/)

**May**

[Why Harry Potter is Not a Horcrux](https://thesffblog.com/2019/05/why-harry-potter-is-not-a-horcrux/)

[Jack’s Bad Movies: Predator 2 (1990)](https://thesffblog.com/2019/05/jacks-bad-movies-predator-2-1990/)

**April**

[FanX Salt Lake Comic Convention (Spring 2019)](https://thesffblog.com/2019/04/fanx-salt-lake-comic-convention-spring-2019/#more-4963)

[Avengers: Endgame Predictions](https://thesffblog.com/2019/04/avengers-endgame-predictions/)

[Highlights from 2019 – 1st Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2019/04/highlights-from-2019-1st-quarter/)

[Jack’s Bad Movies: 2001: A Space Odyssey (1968)](https://thesffblog.com/2019/04/jacks-bad-movies-2001-a-space-odyssey-1968/)

**March**

[Jack’s Bad Movies: DragonLance: Dragons of Autumn Twilight (2008)](https://thesffblog.com/2019/03/jacks-bad-movies-dragonlance-dragons-of-autumn-twilight-2008/)

**February**

[The Second Formic War & Fleet School](https://thesffblog.com/2019/02/the-second-formic-war-fleet-school/)

**January**

[Highlights from 2018 - 4th Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2019/01/highlights-from-2018-4th-quarter/)

Comment: The most amusing part of the Dragonlance film, for me, was that Tanis seems to live up to being "half-elven" in that his ears are pointed in some scenes and round in others.

Answer (score 10):

### 2016

**December**

[Assassin’s Creed – A (mostly) spoiler-free review](https://thesffblog.com/2016/12/assassins-creed-a-mostly-spoiler-free-review/)

**November**

[Jack’s Bad Movies – Alien Uprising (2012)](https://thesffblog.com/2016/11/jacks-bad-movies-alien-uprising/)

[Doctor Strange – A (mostly) spoiler-free review](https://thesffblog.com/2016/11/doctor-strange-a-mostly-spoiler-free-review/)

**October**

[Timeless – Pilot](https://thesffblog.com/2016/10/timeless-pilot/)

[Highlights from 2016 – 3rd Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2016/10/highlights-from-2016-3rd-quarter/)

**September**

[A review of the Stonewylde series](https://thesffblog.com/2016/09/a-review-of-the-stonewylde-series/)

[Salt Lake Comic Con 2016 Recap](https://thesffblog.com/2016/09/salt-lake-comic-con-2016-recap/)

[Coverage of Salt Lake Comic Con 2016](https://thesffblog.com/2016/08/coverage-of-salt-lake-comic-con-2016/)

**August**

[The Rise of the Red Shadow – Prequel to the Book of Deacon Trilogy by Joseph Lallo Review](https://thesffblog.com/2016/08/the-rise-of-the-red-shadow-prequel-to-the-book-of-deacon-trilogy-by-joseph-lallo-review/)

[The Book of Deacon trilogy by Joseph Lallo (spoilers)](https://thesffblog.com/2016/08/the-book-of-deacon-trilogy-by-joseph-lallo-spoilers/)

[Fant4stic: A Review](https://thesffblog.com/2016/08/fant4stic-a-review/)

[Star Trek 50 Day 5: Getting deep into DS9, Star Trek writers reflect on the TNG era, and the Star Trek Rat Pack steals the show!](https://thesffblog.com/2016/08/star-trek-50-day-5-getting-deep-into-ds9-star-trek-writers-reflect-on-the-tng-era-and-the-star-trek-rat-pack-steals-the-show/)

[Star Trek 50 Day 4: Captains Shatner, Bakula, and Mulgrew, Bakula’s talking to Fuller, more TNG stars, Walter Koenig, and Star Trek The Concert!](https://thesffblog.com/2016/08/star-trek-50-day-4-captains-shatner-bakula-and-mulgrew-bakulas-talking-to-fuller-more-tng-stars-walter-koenig-and-star-trek-the-concert/)

[Star Trek 50 Day 3: New TOS footage, George Takei, getting candid with TNG and Voyager stars, and a DS9 documentary in the works!](https://thesffblog.com/2016/08/star-trek-50-day-3-new-tos-footage-george-takei-getting-candid-with-tng-and-voyager-stars-and-a-ds9-documentary-in-the-works/)

[Star Trek 50 Day 2: Ferengi fun, Whoopi Goldberg, and Klingon karaoke!](https://thesffblog.com/2016/08/star-trek-50-day-2-ferengi-fun-whoopi-goldberg-and-klingon-karaoke/)

[Star Trek 50 Day 1: Gorn Santa bearing gifts, Leonard Nimoy memories, and a raucous Klingon talk show](https://thesffblog.com/2016/08/star-trek-50-day-1-gorn-santa-bearing-gifts-leonard-nimoy-memories-and-a-raucous-klingon-talk-show/)

[Coverage of Star Trek 50th Anniversary Celebration for SFF:SE!](https://thesffblog.com/2016/08/coverage-of-star-trek-50th-anniversary-celebration-for-sffse/)

**July**

[The Martian Novel by Andy Weir (Spoilers)](https://thesffblog.com/2016/07/the-martian-novel-by-andy-weir-spoilers/)

[Review – Star Trek Beyond](https://thesffblog.com/2016/07/star-trek-beyond/)

[Doctor Who isn’t really about time travel](https://thesffblog.com/2016/07/doctor-who-isnt-really-about-time-travel/)

[Jack’s Bad Movies – The Fifth Wave](https://thesffblog.com/2016/07/jacks-bad-movies-the-fifth-wave-2/)

[Review of the Duncton Chronicles by William Horwood](https://thesffblog.com/2016/07/review-of-the-duncton-chronicles-by-william-horwood/)

[Highlights from 2016 – 2nd Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2016/07/highlights-from-2016-2nd-quarter/)

**June**

[Why The Shannara Chronicles by Terry Brooks Is Worth Reading](https://thesffblog.com/2016/06/why-the-shannara-chronicles-by-terry-brooks-is-worth-reading/)

[The Riyria Revelations by Michael J. Sullivan and why it is the BEST fantasy series EVER!](https://thesffblog.com/2016/06/the-riyria-revelations-by-michael-j-sullivan-and-why-it-is-the-best-fantasy-series-ever/)

[Jack’s Bad Movies – Automata](https://thesffblog.com/2016/06/jacks-bad-movies-automata/)

[Doctor Who Series 9 Review – Part 2 of 2](https://thesffblog.com/2016/06/doctor-who-series-9-review-part-2-of-2/)

**May**

[The Great Science-Fiction/Fantasy TV Showdown: Final Round](https://thesffblog.com/2016/05/the-great-science-fictionfantasy-tv-showdown-final-round/)

[X-Men: Apocalypse spoiler-free review](https://thesffblog.com/2016/05/x-men-apocalypse-spoiler-free-review/)

[The Great Science-Fiction/Fantasy TV Showdown: Round 4](https://thesffblog.com/2016/05/the-great-science-fictionfantasy-tv-showdown-round-4/)

[A Guide to the Marvel Cinematic Multiverse](https://thesffblog.com/2016/05/a-guide-to-the-marvel-cinematic-multiverse/)

[The Great Science-Fiction/Fantasy TV Showdown! – Results and Round 3 (2nd Edition)](https://thesffblog.com/2016/05/the-great-science-fictionfantasy-tv-showdown-results-and-round-3-2nd-edition/)

[The Great Science-Fiction/Fantasy TV Showdown! – Results and Round Two](https://thesffblog.com/2016/05/the-great-science-fictionfantasy-tv-showdown-results-and-round-two/)

**April**

[The Great Science-Fiction/Fantasy TV Showdown!](https://thesffblog.com/2016/04/the-great-science-fictionfantasy-tv-showdown/)

[Batman v. Superman: Not a Review](https://thesffblog.com/2016/04/batman-v-superman-not-a-review/)

[Highlights from 2016 – 1st Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2016/04/highlights-from-2016-1st-quarter/)

[Doctor Who Series 9 Review – Part 1 of 2](https://thesffblog.com/2016/04/doctor-who-series-9-review-part-1-of-2/)

**March**

[Salt Lake Comic Con FanX 2016 – Celebrity Panels](https://thesffblog.com/2016/03/salt-lake-comic-con-fanx-2016-celebrity-panels/)

[Daredevil Season Two](https://thesffblog.com/2016/03/daredevil-season-two/)

[Jack’s Bad Movies: Wing Commander](https://thesffblog.com/2016/03/jacks-bad-movies-wing-commander/)

**February**

[Jack’s Bad Movies: Highlander II: The Quickening](https://thesffblog.com/2016/02/jacks-bad-movies-highlander-ii-the-quickening/)

[Deadpool Review](https://thesffblog.com/2016/02/deadpool-review/)

[Lego Marvel’s Avengers – A First Look](https://thesffblog.com/2016/02/lego-marvels-avengers-a-first-look/)

**January**

[The 13 Commandments from the TNG Bible.](https://thesffblog.com/2016/01/the-13-commandments-from-the-tng-bible/)

[On The Death of a Science Fiction Icon: A Celebration of David Bowie’s Life and Legacy](https://thesffblog.com/2016/01/on-the-death-of-a-science-fiction-icon-a-celebration-of-david-bowies-life-and-legacy/)

[Highlights from 2015 – 4th Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2016/01/highlights-from-2015-4th-quarter/)

Answer (score 9):

### 2015

**November**

[Jessica Jones season one review](https://thesffblog.com/2015/11/jessica-jones-season-one-review/)

[A Guide To The DC Cinematic Multiverse](https://thesffblog.com/2015/11/a-guide-to-the-dc-cinematic-multiverse/)

**October**

[Story where the number 3 is the monster: Finally Answered!](https://thesffblog.com/2015/10/story-where-the-number-3-is-the-monster-finally-answered/)

[Highlights from 2015 – 3rd Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2015/10/highlights-from-2015-3rd-quarter/)

**September**

[Salt Lake Comic Con 2015 Summary](https://thesffblog.com/2015/09/salt-lake-comic-con-2015-summary/)

[Minority Report – Pilot](https://thesffblog.com/2015/09/minority-report-pilot/)

**August**

[Live Chat: The Day the Earth Stood Still (1951)](https://thesffblog.com/2015/08/live-chat-the-day-the-earth-stood-still-1951/)

[Fantastic Four: A (mildly spoilery) review!](https://thesffblog.com/2015/08/fantastic-four-a-mildly-spoilery-review/)

**July**

[Jack’s Bad Movies – Left Behind](https://thesffblog.com/2015/07/jacks-bad-movies-left-behind/)

[The Solarian War Saga](https://thesffblog.com/2015/07/the-solarian-war-saga/)

[Ant-Man: A (mildly spoilery) review!](https://thesffblog.com/2015/07/ant-man-a-mildly-spoilery-review/)

[Revisiting The Terminator](https://thesffblog.com/2015/07/revisiting-the-terminator/)

[Highlights from 2015 – 2nd Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2015/07/highlights-from-2015-2nd-quarter/)

**June**

[Gorilla vs. Shark? Not so fast…](https://thesffblog.com/2015/06/gorilla-vs-shark-not-so-fast/)

[Mutants in the Marvel Universe](https://thesffblog.com/2015/06/mutants-in-the-marvel-universe/)

[Jack’s Bad Movies – Jinn](https://thesffblog.com/2015/06/jacks-bad-movies-jinn/)

**May**

[Stitchers – Early Episode 1 Release](https://thesffblog.com/2015/05/stitchers-early-episode-1-release/)

[Supergirl “leaked Pilot” – An almost completely spoiler-free review](https://thesffblog.com/2015/05/supergirl-leaked-pilot-an-almost-completely-spoiler-free-review/)

**April**

[Highlights from 2015 – 1st Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2015/04/highlights-from-2014-1st-quarter-2/)

**March**

[Jack’s Bad Movies – Yor, the Hunter from the Future](https://thesffblog.com/2015/03/jacks-bad-movies-yor-the-hunter-from-the-future/)

[Review – Cinderella](https://thesffblog.com/2015/03/cinderella-review/)

**February**

[Science Fiction, Fantasy and Genre](https://thesffblog.com/2015/02/science-fiction-fantasy-and-genre/)

[Salt Lake Comic Con FanX 2015 – Heroes, Villains, and Anti-Heroes in Harry Potter: Who’s Who? Panel](https://thesffblog.com/2015/02/salt-lake-comic-con-fanx-2015-heroes-villains-and-anti-heroes-in-harry-potter-whos-who-panel/)

[Salt Lake Comic Con FanX 2015 – KIDCON and Disney Princesses](https://thesffblog.com/2015/02/salt-lake-comic-con-fanx-2015-kidcon-and-disney-princesses/)

[Featured Answer: How long was Bill Murray’s character supposed to be in a time loop in the film “Groundhog Day”?](https://thesffblog.com/2015/02/featured-question-how-long-was-bill-murrays-character-supposed-to-be-in-a-time-loop-in-the-film-groundhog-day/)

**January**

[Salt Lake Comic Con FanX 2015 – Tom Felton Panel](https://thesffblog.com/2015/01/salt-lake-comic-con-fanx-2015-tom-felton-panel/)

[The (new) Star Wars Canon guide](https://thesffblog.com/2015/01/the-new-star-wars-canon-guide/)

[Agent Carter – Pilot Episode](https://thesffblog.com/2015/01/agent-carter-pilot-episode/)

[Highlights from 2014 – 4th Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2015/01/highlights-from-2014-4th-quarter/)

Answer (score 8):

### 2013

**December**

[TV Shows with a Supernatural Theme](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/12/tv-shows-with-a-supernatural-theme/)

[Review – Frozen](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/12/review-frozen/)

**November**

[Review – Thor: The Dark World](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/11/review-thor-the-dark-world/)

[Guide to either loving or hating Ender’s Game (film)](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/11/guide-to-either-loving-or-hating-enders-game-film/)

**October**

[Highlights from 2013 – 3rd Quarter](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/10/highlights-from-2013-3rd-quarter/)

**September**

[Live Chat: Star Trek TOS “Space Seed”](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/live-chat-star-trek-tos-space-seed/)

**July**

[Review – Turbo](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/07/review-turbo/)

[Review – World War Z](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/07/review-world-war-zed/)

[Highlights from 2013 – 2nd Quarter](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/07/highlights-from-2013-2nd-quarter/)

**June**

[Review – Man Of Steel](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/06/man-of-steel/)

**May**

[Review: Iron Man 3](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/review-iron-man-3/)

**April**

[Highlights from 2013 – 1st Quarter](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/04/highlights-from-2013-1st-quarter/)

[Reviews: The Croods](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/04/reviews-the-croods/)

Answer (score 8):

### 2014

**December**

[Technologies We Should Have In 2015](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/12/technologies-we-should-have-in-2015/)

[Jack’s Bad Movies – AE: Apocalypse Earth](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/12/jacks-bad-movies-ae-apocalypse-earth/)

[Doom Star Series (books)](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/12/doom-star-series-books/)

**November**

[Detective Comics #27 – Introduction of the Batman](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/11/detective-comics-27-introduction-of-the-batman/)

[Science Fiction Technologies that People are Hoping for in Their Lifetime](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/11/science-fiction-technologies-that-people-are-hoping-for-in-their-lifetime/)

**October**

[Favorite Questions and Answers of All Time](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/10/favorite-questions-and-answers-of-all-time/)

[The Flash – Pilot Episode](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/10/the-flash-pilot-episode/)

[Highlights from 2014 – 3rd Quarter](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/10/highlights-from-2014-3rd-quarter/)

**September**

[Salt Lake Comic Con 2014 Report](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/09/salt-lake-comic-con-overall/)

[Salt Lake Comic Con 2014 – Marvel Movies Phase III Panel](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/09/salt-lake-comic-con-marvel-movies-phase-iii-panel/)

**July**

[Starship Troopers – The Mobile Infantry definitely does not accept Hippies!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/07/starship-troopers-the-mobile-infantry-definitely-does-not-accept-hippies/)

[Highlights from 2014 – 2nd Quarter](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/07/highlights-from-2014-2nd-quarter/)

[The First Formic War (Ender’s Game Prequel Trilogy)](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/07/the-first-formic-war-enders-game-prequel-trilogy/)

**April**

[Salt Lake Comic Con Fan Xperience](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/04/salt-lake-comic-con-fan-xperience/)

[Highlights from 2014 – 1st Quarter](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/04/highlights-from-2014-1st-quarter/)

**March**

[The 100 – Pilot Episode](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/03/the-100-pilot-episode/)

[Movies With Time-Traveling Robots](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/03/movies-with-time-traveling-robots/)

**January**

[Highlights from 2013 – 4th Quarter](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/01/highlights-from-2013-4th-quarter/)

Answer (score 8):

### 2021

**December**

[The Matrix Resurrections Review: 100 Words Or Fewer – Spoiler Free](https://thesffblog.com/2021/12/the-matrix-resurrections-review-100-words-or-fewer-spoiler-free/)

[Spider-Man: No Way Home - Spoiler Free](https://thesffblog.com/2021/12/spider-man-no-way-home-spoiler-free/)

**November**

[The Wakanda Files](https://thesffblog.com/2021/11/the-wakana-files/)

**October**

[Favorite Question and Answers from Third Quarter 2021](https://thesffblog.com/2021/10/favorite-questions-and-answers-from-third-quarter-2021/)

**August**

[Favorite Question and Answers from Second Quarter 2021](https://thesffblog.com/2021/08/favorite-question-and-answers-from-second-quarter-2021/)

**July**

[Mark D. Owen’s Impact](https://thesffblog.com/2021/07/mark-d-owens-impact/)

**June**

[The Death Gate Cycle](https://thesffblog.com/2021/06/the-death-gate-cycle/)

[Andy Weir’s Project Hail Mary: A Novel](https://thesffblog.com/2021/06/andy-weirs-project-hail-mary-a-novel/)

**May**

[Jack’s Bad Movies: The Scorpion King 4: Quest for Power (2015)](https://thesffblog.com/2021/05/jacks-bad-movies-the-scorpion-king-4-quest-for-power-2015/)

**April**

[Favorite Question and Answers from First Quarter 2021](https://thesffblog.com/2021/04/favorite-question-and-answers-from-first-quarter-2021/)

**March**

[The Alpha Protocol](https://thesffblog.com/2021/03/the-alpha-protocol/)

[Rapid Fire Book Reviews](https://thesffblog.com/2021/03/rapid-fire-book-reviews/)

[Giants Series](https://thesffblog.com/2021/03/giants-series/)

**February**

[Favorite Questions and Answers from Fourth Quarter 2020](https://thesffblog.com/2021/02/favorite-questions-and-answers-from-fourth-quater-2020/)

**January**

[SFF Stack Exchange is starting topic challenges](https://thesffblog.com/2021/01/sff-stack-exchange-is-starting-topic-challenges/)

[Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange 10th Anniversary](https://thesffblog.com/2021/01/science-fiction-fantasy-stack-exchange-10th-anniversary/)

Answer (score 7):

### 2022

**November**

[Firefly episodes ranked best to worst](https://thesffblog.com/2022/11/firefly-episodes-ranked-best-to-worst/)

[Favorite Questions and Answers from Third Quarter 2022](https://thesffblog.com/2022/11/favorite-questions-and-answers-from-third-quarter-2022/)

**August**

[Prey (2022) – In 100 words or less Spoiler Free](https://thesffblog.com/2022/08/prey-2022-in-100-words-or-less-spoiler-free/)

[Jack’s Bad Movies: Johnny Mnemonic (1995)](https://thesffblog.com/2022/08/jacks-bad-movies-johnny-mnemonic-1995/)

**July**

[Favorite Questions and Answers from Second Quarter 2022](https://thesffblog.com/2022/07/favorite-questions-and-answers-from-second-quarter-2022/)

[It’s Time to Give Star Trek: The Motion Picture Another Look](https://thesffblog.com/2022/07/its-time-to-give-star-trek-the-motion-picture-another-look/)

**June**

[Jack’s Bad Movies: Godzilla vs Kong (2021)](https://thesffblog.com/2022/06/jacks-bad-movies-godzilla-vs-kong-2021/)

[Sonic the Hedgehog 2 (2022)](https://thesffblog.com/2022/06/sonic-the-hedgehog-2-2022/)

**April**

[Favorite Questions and Answers from First Quarter 2022](https://thesffblog.com/2022/04/favorite-questions-and-answers-from-first-quarter-2022/)

[Jack’s Bad Movies: Blade Runner (1982)](https://thesffblog.com/2022/04/jacks-bad-movies-blade-runner-1982/)

**March**

[Netflix’s Space Force: Season 2](https://thesffblog.com/2022/03/netflixs-space-force-season-2/)

[The Batman in 100 words or less – Spoiler Free](https://thesffblog.com/2022/03/the-batman-in-100-words-or-less-spoiler-free/)

**February**

[Jack’s Bad Movies: Ai Love You](https://thesffblog.com/2022/02/jacks-bad-movies-ai-love-you/)

**January**

[Orson Scott Card’s The Last Shadow](https://thesffblog.com/2022/01/orson-scott-cards-the-last-shadow/)

[Favorite Questions and Answers from Fourth Quarter 2021](https://thesffblog.com/2022/01/favorite-questions-and-answers-from-fourth-quarter-2021/)

Comment: My word. It appears that we have some kind of blog

Answer (score 6):

### 2012

**October**

[Brickcon 2012](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/10/brickcon-2012/)

**September**

[Space Saga – Chapter 1: The accident](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/space-saga-chapter-1-the-accident/)

**August**

[Star Wars Identities : The Exhibition](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/08/star-wars-identities-the-exhibition/)

[Live Chat – Star Trek TOS “And The Children Shall Lead”](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/08/live-chat-star-trek-tos-and-the-children-shall-lead/)

**June**

[HeroesCon 2012 Report](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/heroescon-2012-report/)

**May**

[Harry Potter Movie Marathon Highlights](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/05/harry-potter-movie-marathon-highlights/)

**April**

[Avengers vs. X-Men results! Winners announced!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/04/avengers-vs-x-men-results-winners-announced/)

[Topic of the Week Contest: The Legend of Korra](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/04/topic-of-the-week-contest-the-legend-of-korra/)

[Avengers vs. X-Men is here!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/04/avengers-vs-x-men-is-here/)

[A month of comic exploration](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/04/a-month-of-comic-exploration/)

**March**

[Stack Exchange is giving away sets of Game of Thrones: Season 1 on Blu-Ray and DVD!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/03/stack-exchange-is-giving-away-sets-of-game-of-thrones-season-1-on-blu-ray-and-dvd/)

[SciFi.StackExchange in Practical Use – A newcomer’s journey to Doctor Who.](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/03/scifi-stackexchange-in-practical-use-a-newcomers-journey-to-doctor-who/)

[The Last Question](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/03/the-last-question/)

**February**

[New Mid-season Sci-fi & Fantasy TV](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/02/new-mid-season-sci-fi-fantasy-tv/)

**January**

[Moderator Elections](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/01/moderator-elections/)

Answer (score 6):

### 2020

**December**

[Ready Player Two](https://thesffblog.com/2020/12/ready-player-two/)

**October**

[Highlights from 2020 3rd Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2020/10/highlights-from-2020-3rd-quarter/)

**September**

[Tenet (2020)](https://thesffblog.com/2020/09/tenet-2020-a-review/)

**July**

[Space Force](https://thesffblog.com/2020/07/space-force/)

[Highlights from 2020 1st & 2nd Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2020/07/highlights-from-2020-1st-2nd-quarter/)

**June**

[Westworld](https://thesffblog.com/2020/06/westworld/)

**March**

[Jack’s Bad Movies: Doom Annihilation (2019)](https://thesffblog.com/2020/03/jacks-bad-movies-doom-annihilation-2019/)

**January**

[Loop – The Distress Call. A science-fiction game that pays homage to science fiction and narrative games](https://thesffblog.com/2020/01/loop-the-distress-call-a-science-fiction-game-that-pays-homage-to-science-fiction-and-narrative-games/)

[Highlights from 2019 - 4th Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2020/01/highlights-from-2019-4th-quarter/)

[2020 – A year of alien invasions](https://thesffblog.com/2020/01/2020-a-year-of-alien-invasions/)

Answer (score 5):

### 2011

**December**

[The Dark Mirror / Blade of Fortriu](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/12/the-dark-mirror-blade-of-fortriu/)

[Featured Question: E.T. & Star Wars](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/12/featured-question-e-t-star-wars/)

[Launch!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/12/launch/)

[Movies Sister Site Launches](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/12/movies-sister-site-launches/)

**October**

[SciFi.StackExchange in Practical Use – In what order should the Star Wars movies be watched?](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/scifi-stackexchange-in-practical-use-in-what-order-should-the-star-wars-movies-be-watched/)

[Sci-Fi Stack Exchange at New York Comic Con](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/sci-fi-stack-exchange-at-new-york-comic/)

[Re-evaluating the end of “Planetary”](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/re-evaluating-the-end-of-planetary/)

[Q&A with Jim Gibbons of Dark Horse Comics](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/qa-with-jim-gibbons-of-dark-horse-comics/)

[Featured Question: In The Lord of the Rings, what important background information is contained in the poems?](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/featured-question-in-the-lord-of-the-rings-what-important-background-information-is-contained-in-the-poems/)

[Stack Exchange is giving away 3-day passes to New York Comic Con](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/nyccse/)

**September**

[Contagion – ‘Jaws’ for the Flu](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/contagion-jaws-for-the-flu/)

[Review: Roger Zelazny, A Night in the Lonesome October](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/review-roger-zelazny-a-night-in-the-lonesome-october/)

[Amazon Kindle now servicing over 11,000 public libraries](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/amazon-kindle-now-servicing-over-11000-public-libraries/)

[The Sci-fi & Fantasy Fall 2011 TV Season](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/the-sci-fi-fantasy-fall-2011-tv-season/)

[Stack Exchange Helps Out a Superman Fan](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/stack-exchange-helps-out-a-superman-fan/)

[DC’s new 52](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/dcs-new-52/)

[Digital Vs. Physical – How do digital comics stand up to the tried and true?](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/digital-vs-physical-%e2%80%93-how-do-digital-comics-stand-up-to-the-tried-and-true/)

[Review: The Throne of Fire, by Rick Riordan](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/review-the-throne-of-fire-by-rick-riordan/)

[Comic Recommendation: Y: The Last Man](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/comic-recommendation-y-the-last-man/)

[Interview: Jason Snell, host of The Incomparable SF&F Podcast](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/interview-jason-snell-host-of-the-incomparable-sff-podcast/)

[What has a love of science-fiction done for me?](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/what-has-a-love-of-science-fiction-done-for-me/)

[@stackscifi improvements](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/stackscifi-improvements/)

**August**

[Lessons Learned: Lord of the Rings](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/lessons_learn_lot/)

[Review of Another Earth](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/review-of-another-earth/)

[Literature Sister Site Launches](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/literature-sister-site-launches/)

[iPad PADD application: disappointing](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/ipad-padd-application-disappointing/)

[Elvis Has Left the Building](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/elvis-has-left-the-building/)

[The Hugo Awards: Live Coverage](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/the-hugo-awards-live-coverage/)

[Costumes Everywhere](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/costumes-everywhere/)

[Instant Art!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/instant-art/)

[Fannish Humor](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/fannish-humor/)

[Tricky Pixie in Concert](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/tricky-pixie-in-concert/)

[Steve Jackson at Worldcon](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/steve-jackson-at-worldcon/)

[Welcome to Worldcon!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/welcome-to-worldcon/)

[Stack Exchange is going to Worldcon!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/stack-exchange-is-going-to-worldcon/)

[Featured Question: Why Do We Hear Leia’s Theme During Kenobi’s Death](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/featured-question-why-do-we-hear-leias-theme-during-kenobis-death/)

[Artemis Fowl](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/artemis-fowl/)

Answer (score 4):

### 2023

**September**

- [Salt Lake FanX Comic Convention Fall 2023](https://thesffblog.com/2023/09/salt-lake-fanx-comic-convention-fall-2023/)

**July**

- [Jack’s Bad Movies: Snake (2018)](https://thesffblog.com/2023/07/jacks-bad-movies-snake-2018/)
- [Favorite Question and Answers from Second Quarter 2023](https://thesffblog.com/2023/07/favorite-question-and-answers-from-second-quarter-2023/)

**June**

- [The First Officer Alpha Protocol Book 2](https://thesffblog.com/2023/06/this-first-officer-the-alpha-protocol-book-2/)

**April**

- [Favorite Question and Answers from First Quarter 2023](https://thesffblog.com/2023/04/favorite-question-and-answers-from-first-quarter-2023/)
- [Jack’s Bad Movies: Indiana Jones: Raiders of the Lost Ark (1981)](https://thesffblog.com/2023/04/jacks-bad-movies-indiana-jones-raiders-of-the-lost-ark-1981/)

**March**

- [Jack’s Bad Movies: Black Adam (2022)](https://thesffblog.com/2023/03/jacks-bad-movies-black-adam-2022/)

**February**

- [The Angry Birds](https://thesffblog.com/2023/02/the-angry-birds/)

**January**

- [Jack’s Bad Movies – Morbius (2022)](https://thesffblog.com/2023/01/jacks-bad-movies-morbius-2022/)
- [Favorite Questions and Answers from Fourth Quarter 2022](https://thesffblog.com/2023/01/favorite-questions-and-answers-from-fourth-quarter-2022/)