# Can we get our blog link back, please?

Tags: feature-request, design

The new topbar just arrived to SFF! *confetti shower*

Before that, and before the blogs were discontinued, we used to have a link to [our very own blog](https://thesffblog.com/) in the SE dropdown menu. It was removed after SE discontinued hosting community blogs.

However, our blog still lives and is updated regularly. Right now we have to access it through the link: https://thesffblog.com, or through this meta: [Latest Blog Post: Jack’s Bad Movies: Colossal (2016)](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11051/latest-blog-post-jack-s-bad-movies-colossal-2016).

I think it'd be easier to find the blog for new users if there was a link in the dropdown. It'd also be easier for everyone else to find it.

Can we have it back, please?

Comment: That might be a liability problem, seeing how that blog is entirely unofficial from SE's point of view. Did you check if this was asked/proposed before? I'm sure it came up during the whole blog migration process. Not sure the new topbar changes much in that regard.

Comment: So, the link to the blog only went to the new blog, because one of the SE employees kindly set up a redirect for `http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/` to go to `https://thesffblog.com` as part of the transition process. As of _right now_, that redirect is still in place, but I never expected that to be permanent.

Comment: @Blackwood re your edit: the spelling is something of an [XKCD meme](https://blog.xkcd.com/)

Comment: I don't mind you fixing it, just saying :D

Comment: Sorry. That one passed me by. I've put it back the way it was.

Comment: Worldbuilding also has an active blog and would want the same thing.  (We never had the link because we were too late for blogoverflow; we built ours from scratch elsewhere.)  When I asked about better linking I got pushback because it blurs the official/unofficial line.  Here are some relevant MSE posts: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285998/162102, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287921/162102.

Comment: Is the "bl**a**g" in the title an inside joke?

Comment: @much it's an [XKCD reference](https://blog.xkcd.com/) :-)

Comment: Can an sff mood make a *permanent* entry in our sidebar announcements? Or do they have to expire?

Comment: @Valorum see comments above re blag/blog

Comment: @Randal'Thor - The obscure joke went right over my head

Comment: @Valorum You're not the only one. The revision history on this post is quite funny.

Answer (score 7):

When Stack Exchange discontinued the blogs and began phasing them out, we were sort-of warned this might happened.

What SE committed to was that, as long as we maintained the correct link structure on the off-site blog, they would maintain the redirect from `scifi.blogoverflow.com` to our blog on `thesffblog.com`. That redirect does still work, so any links you already have to the blog redirect properly. Beyond that, we knew the SF/F blog was no longer something SE considered "theirs".

SE doesn't have site blogs anymore; as far as I can find, we're the *only* one who has an active redirect from `blogoverflow`. Of the few other sites that even had content on their blogs, they're now just archives. It's unlikely that we're going to get SE to change their top bar just for one site, and for an unofficial, off-site content host at that,

Comment: IIRC Worldbuilding does have a Medium blog... how many of us would have to band together before they started caring?

Comment: Yes, Worldbuilding has an _off-site, unoffiical_ blog, exactly like we have. SE doesn't consider blogs to be part of the network infrastructure anymore, and we weren't persuasive enough to change their minds on that, so I doubt any number of users on a single site is going to change their minds about linking to an unofficial blog.

Comment: Yeah, this pretty much covers it. It's super cool that you're still making your blog work, but since official community blogs were discontinued, blog links weren't part of the Big Official Requirements Doc for the current network-wide standard top bar. (That's a figure of speech, I don't know if there was a formal requirements thing.)